# How to write dynamic SQL to select column names based on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a use case where I want to write a dynamic sql which would select the column names dynamically based on the other table.

Query 1: select T_SERIES_VALUE from MONTHS_MAPPING where TIME_PERIOD = 'JUN-2023'; -- T66 is the output

Query 2: select aaaa, bbbb, ***OUTPUT OF QUERY1*** as 'Current_Month' from MAIN_TABLE;

As I am unable to handle this multiple columns in a sql function/proc in this use case, I created a sql TYPE of Object/Table and then using bulk collect as below. Proc is compiling. But when I execute the proc, I am getting inconsistent data types error. But I see the datatypes of object type and db values from MAIN_TABLE are one and the same.

I tried below:

Type 1:

```
create or replace type cds_type_o1 as Object 
(
aaaa    VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
,bbbb   VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
,Tx NUMBER(38,10)
);
```

Type 2:
``
create or replace type cds_type_t1 is table of cds_type_o1 ;

``

Proc:

```
create or replace procedure test_bulk_collect_table (reporting_period IN VARCHAR2)
 is
   v_cm_sql varchar2(256);
   v_cm varchar2(256);

    v_output_execute varchar2(256);
    v_output cds_type_t1;
  begin
     v_cm_sql:='select T_SERIES_VALUE from MONTHS_MAPPING where TIME_PERIOD = '||reporting_period; -- T61
      execute immediate v_cm_sql into v_cm; --T66

     v_output_execute:= 'select aaaa, bbbb, '|| v_cm ||' from MAIN_TABLE';
      dbms_output.put_line(v_output_execute); --select aaaa, bbbb, T66 from MAIN_TABLE
      *execute immediate v_output_execute bulk collect into v_output;*  --Here I am getting the error while executing it
 dbms_output.put(v_output(0).scenario);
     for i in v_output.first..v_output.last loop
     dbms_output.put(v_output(i).aaaa);
       end loop;
 end test_bulk_collect_table;
```

Now when I execute this proc as
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXEC test_bulk_collect_table('JUN-2023');

I am getting the below error:
Error report -
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TEST_BULK_COLLECT_TABLE", line 15 (execute immediate v_output_execute bulk collect into v_output)
ORA-06512: at line 1
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
*Action:

I am confused with this error, as it is expecting %s and it is also getting %s, any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fetch (or bulk collect) into a list of objects, you need select *objects* not columns.  Hence you just need to add an object constructor in your query, eg

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  type myobj as object ( x int, y int );
  3  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  type mylist is table of myobj;
  3  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    v mylist;
  3  begin
  4    select empno, sal
  5    bulk collect into v
  6    from emp;
  7  end;
  8  /
  from emp;
  *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    v mylist;
  3  begin
  4    select myobj(empno, sal)
  5    bulk collect into v
  6    from emp;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much @Connor for your reply. I am now getting the below error. Sorry, I am a bit new to Oracle, I didn't declare any VARRAY type, however I am getting the below error. Just that the underline table has 60K records.

06532. 00000 -  "Subscript outside of limit"
*Cause:    A subscript was greater than the limit of a varray
           or non-positive for a varray or nested table.
*Action:   Check the program logic and increase the varray limit
           if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you **OVER**complicating things here? Error you got is due to what Connor has already said, but - as there's nothing *dynamic* in code you posted, why are you using dynamic SQL? Everything can be done MUCH simpler. Here's a demo.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table months_mapping as select 'T66' t_series_value, 'T61' time_period from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table main_table as select 1 aaaa, 2 bbbb from dual;

Table created.
```

Types:

```
SQL> create or replace type cds_type_o1 as Object
  2    (aaaa  VARCHAR2(26)
  3    ,bbbb  VARCHAR2(256)
  4    ,Tx    VARCHAR2(10)
  5    );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type cds_type_t1 is table of cds_type_o1;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_bulk_collect_table (reporting_period IN VARCHAR2)
  2  is
  3    v_output cds_type_t1;
  4  begin
  5    select cds_type_o1(a.aaaa, a.bbbb, b.t_series_value)
  6    bulk collect into v_output
  7    from months_mapping b cross join main_table a
  8    where b.time_period = reporting_period;
  9
 10    for i in v_output.first .. v_output.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(v_output(i).aaaa ||' - '|| v_output(i).bbbb ||' - '|| v_output(i).tx);
 12    end loop;
 13  end test_bulk_collect_table;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec test_bulk_collect_table('T61');
1 - 2 - T66

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, Really appreciate it. t_series_value is dynamic in nature. Based on the row value it returns from months_mapping table, I am selecting that value/column from main_table. and this value changes by nature. So I had to go with dynamic sql.

When I try to implement the solution you provided, I am getting 03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None...

Could you please check if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: posting my proc query as the above comment is not allowing more than 166 char.

v_output_execute:= 'select cds_type_o1(aaaa, bbbb, T61)
 bulk collect into v_output
  from MONTHS_MAPPING b cross join MAIN_TABLE a
   where b.time_period = ' || reporting_period;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_output_execute);
      execute immediate v_output_execute ;

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing the obvious ? What about just using a *scalar subquery* and do it in sql ?

```
select 
  aaaa, 
  bbbb, 
  (select T_SERIES_VALUE from MONTHS_MAPPING where TIME_PERIOD = 'JUN-2023') as "Current_Month" 
  from main_table
```

Comment: Hi @Koen Lostrie, unfortunately it's not that simple actually. I tried using the query you mentioned, but instead of returning the actual output of inner select query, it just keep on printing the <T_SERIES_VALUE> in all rows..
eg of output:

``aaaa       bbbb    Current_Month
1111        11112    T61
2222         11112   T61``

Comment: Pls provide enough sample data to reproduce the issue.